# Proving $\lim_{n}\mathbb{P}(X = x_{n}) = 0$ if $\lim_{n} x_{n} = \infty$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a real random variable and let $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n} x_{n} = \infty$. Prove that $\lim_{n}\mathbb{P}(X = x_{n}) = 0$.

I think it follows from the fact that $\mathbb{P}(X\in\mathbb{R})$ is 1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The events $(X \geq N)$ decrease to  empty set so $P(X \geq N) \to 0$. Now $P(X=x_n) \leq P(X \geq N)$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Put these two together and you have a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Another proof could be the following. The event $(X = x_{n})$ is contained on the event $(X > x_{n} - 1)$. The probability of the last event is $1 - F_{X}(x_{n} - 1)$, where $F_{X}$ is the cumulative distribution function. Thus, we have that $\mathbb{P}(X = x_{n})\leq 1 - F_{X}(x_{n} - 1)$. By the Sandwich Rule and the fact that $\lim_{n}F_{X}(x_{n} - 1) = 1$ we have the result.